# Urlopen not opening correct url

Tags: python, url, urllib2, urllib, urlopen

For some reason when calling

```
url = urllib2.urlopen("https://gateway.oar.net/api/siteroles?contact_client_short_name=%s" %clientName)
url = json.loads(url.read())
```

the url that is read is just "https://gateway.oar.net/api/siteroles", is there any reason why the rest of the url is cut off? When I open the inputUrl that i want into chrome, the response is correct and the url is correct.

Any advice?

Thank you In Advance

EDIT:
I tried putting in print(url.getcode()) and it output 200

Comment: could you include the print(url.getcode()) before loads?

Comment: I am betting on 302.

Comment: are you sure you are using a valid uri?
and get use to have an 'r' before the strings... - r"https://...".

Comment: How do you know which URL it's reading? When I go to https://gateway.oar.net/api/siteroles I can't connect.

Comment: its an internal site, you just have to trust me when I saw it's working haha

Comment: I'm using this to try to read in api data, when I look at the data that its getting, its from the default page

Comment: If you don't need credentials and you saw it working, it is now down,

Comment: I'm refreshing and it's working fine right now,
the urlopen code i'm trying to reach is for a specific page within hundreds of the main page, for some reason, instead of going to that page, the code is opening and reading the default page